# The file I am writing out is not matching with the file I am reading in

Tags: python

I have two files, 'tclust.txt' and 'ef_blue.xpk'. 
I want to take in certain charactes from ef_blue.xpk and use them in tclust.txt

```
import re
import sys 
import os 

lines = open('tclust.txt').readlines()
last_line = lines[-1] 

open ('tclust.txt','w').writelines(lines[:-2])

with open("ef_blue.xpl","rt") as f1, open("tclust.txt","a") as f2:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",line)
        if len(float_num)>1:
            f2.writelines(' '*6 +float_num[0] + '0.05' + float_num[1] + '0.05' + '\n')
 f2.writelines(last_line)
```

I'm trying to get my output (tclust.txt) to look like:

[image: What tclust.txt output should be]

This is what it actually is:

[image: What it actually is]

My original tclust file that I'm trying to append

[image: My original tclust.txt file I'm trying to append]

My original ef_blue file

[image: My original ef_blue file]

How can I get my tclust file to look like my output?

Edit1: if I change the line

```
open ('tclust.txt','w').writelines(lines[:-2])
```

to

```
open ('tclust.txt','w').writelines(lines[:-1])
```

My output changes to

[image: What it changes to]

Also, how could I make it so that after each line, the string 'Peak' is followed by the appropriate number as it is in my desired tclust.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import sys 
import os 

i = 0;
f = open("tclust.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
contents = []
with open("ef_blue.xpl","r") as f1:
    for line in f1.readlines():
        float_num = re.findall("[\s][1-9]{1}\.[0-9]+",line)
        if len(float_num)>1:
            i = i + 1
            value = ('Peak ' + str(i) + str(float_num[0]) + ' 0.05' + str(float_num[1]) + ' 0.05' + '\n')
            lines.insert(-1,value)  

f = open("tclust.txt", "w")
for value in lines: 
    f.write(value)
f.close()
```

The code given above should do your job. In `lines.insert(index,value)` index starts with the value 0 for a file.